# OpenGL texture, doesn't like my bmp

Tags: opengl, textures

don't worry, I don't want to ask how to use textures. :)

My problem is:
I'm using several textures. But if I want to change the file name like this:

```
(LoadBMP("grass.bmp", textureImage[3])) // I can see the grass
```

to

```
(LoadBMP("parkett.bmp", textureImage[3])) // No texture, only white color
```

Both pictures are in the same directory and there is no error message.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Sonja
(OpenGL, Visual Studio C++ 2010)

Comment: `LoadBMP` is not an OpenGL function and you haven't provided anywhere near enough context to determine what's actually going on. "Only white" is the default value returned if no texture is set in OpenGL, so it's pretty safe to assume that loading fails. As for the details, you'll have to look into LoadBMP - just step through it with a debugger and check what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, those textures use a different format (`.bmp` is not just a single format) and your function only supports one.

The simplest and best solution is to use a good library to load your textures, instead of some mystical `LoadBMP`. I recommend [SOIL - Simple OpenGL Image Loader.](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) Just add it to your project and you'll be able to load any `bmp`, `jpg` or `png` textures to an OpenGL texture ID with a single function call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is, it is a project for university and I have to use the LoadBMP of my professor. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: @Sonja: How about making sure that both images are in `bmp` format?

Comment: Try: open the bad bitmap with GIMP, save as 24-bit BMP in another filename, try again with the new file. I cannot tell exactly what happens because i don't know either the bitmaps nor the content of LoadBMP.

Comment: Hm I opened the picture in PhotoFiltre and saved it as BMP. So it should be the correct format shouldn't it?

Comment: I have no idea what is the "correct format", as understood by "whatever LoadBMP understands". If your image was, say, 8-bit BMP, then opening and saving in some application could save it in the same format as it was before. Make sure you save as 24-bit BMP, it's the most likely option.

Comment: Tried it with GIMP, same problem :(

Comment: Can you host those two images (working and not working) somewhere and show them? (Just make sure it's not a place when they'd get converted to JPG after upload.)

Answer (score 0):

Can just assume your second BMP has wrong internal data format (non-BGR or something like that). Agreed with Kos - you should try using some libraries for this purpose. There are lots of 'em - [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/), [SDL_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/), [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/)...

Answer (score 0):

Are the dimensions of the non-working texture powers of 2 (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...)? If not, then that's why it's not working. Either scale or pad.